# How to make fragment cover AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I currently have an app where I pull up an addTask Fragment upon clicking a FAB button. I would like it to cover the AppBarLayout so that I can bring up a different ToolBar with the fragment. Currently the Fragment is being placed directly below the current AppBar.

The fragment is pulled up in the FrameLayout. I tried removing the scrolling behavior because I saw someone do something similar in another post, but then my fragment does not appear at all.

Main_Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expanded="false"
        app:layout_behavior="com.timeblocks.timeblocks.ScrollingCalendarBehavior"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

                <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
                    android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="#FFC107"
                    app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayBackgroundColor="#BBDEFB"
                    app:compactCalendarTextColor="#fff"
                    app:compactCalendarTextSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/date_picker_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date_picker_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/date_picker_arrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/date_picker_text_view"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/date_picker_text_view"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,RtlHardcoded" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabTaskHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fabEvent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:text="Add Task"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabTask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabEventHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:text="Add Event"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabEvent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works. I surrounded the `CoordinatorLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` and then placed the `FrameLayout` after the `CoordinatorLayout`.